# Mongodb equals with reference to another collection

Tags: mongodb

I'm trying to execute mongodb query which collects object by hierarchy with some restrictions. Currently I'm facing problem with restriction clause: I need to check equality between values from different collection:

```
db.getCollection('collection1').aggregate([{ 
            "$graphLookup": {
                "from": "collection1",
                "startWith": "$childrenIds",
                "connectFromField": "childrenIds",
                "connectToField": "_id",
                "as": "childrenResult",
                "restrictSearchWithMatch": {"$or": [{"type": {"$ne": "Some Type"}},{"db.getCollection('collection2').findOne({'_id': 'someReferenceFieldFromCollection1')}).status": {"$eq": "ENABLED"}}]}
            }
        }, {
            "$unwind": "$childrenResult"
        }, {
            "$replaceRoot": {
                "newRoot": "$childrenResult"
            }
        }])
```

It seems like I cant use nested mongodb query. Still, when I execute nested query

```
db.getCollection('collection2').findOne({'_id': 'someId')}).status
```

I got its status value.

Even if I hardcode the id, I'm doing lookup in collection2 my hierarchical query doesn't work.

So my question is how can I do this type of inner query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like mongodb doesn't support nested queries. Thus I've refactored my service code.